Resources on how to write good TCS papers
I am looking for good resources on how to write papers, which could be useful for graduate students in TCS. The internet seems to be full with style books, papers, and online talks on the subject, but most of them seem to be about scientific papers in general, or about CS papers in general, and their advice seems to be either too general or irrelevant to TCS.
I know Oded Goldreich's "How to write a paper", Terry Tao's advice, and the KLR lecture notes on mathematical writing. I'd be happy to hear about other useful resources.

I remember Sanjeev Arora saying in a tribute that reading Papadimitriou's papers was very helpful to him when he was a beginning student. I think reading some classical papers of some authors, seeing different styles, and discussing what one likes and doesn't could be a good exercise.
